# How can I prevent the Require.js optimizer from including the text plugin in optimized files?

Tags: javascript, optimization, requirejs

**tl;dr: How do I keep the text.js plugin out of my optimized file when all my text dependencies are inlined?**

I'm using the [Require.js optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) (via Node) to optimize some of the JS files in my project. I'm using the [text plugin](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#text) to load text dependencies (HTML templates, CSS). I've got a module I want to optimize, including its dependencies, like this:

```
define(['text!core/core.css'], function(styles) {
    // do setup stuff, return an object
});
```

The Require.js docs say that the `core/core.css` file will be inlined when I run the `r.js` optimizer, which I'm invoking like this:

```
$ r.js -o baseUrl=./src name=core out=release/test.js

Tracing dependencies for: core
Uglifying file: c:/path/release/test.js

c:/path/release/test.js
----------------
c:/path/src/text.js
text!core/core.css
c:/path/src/core.js
```

The good news is, this works. When I look at the optimized file, I can see the inlined text, something like this:

```
define("text!core/core.css",[],function(){return"some CSS text"}),
define("core",["text!core/core.css"],function(a){ ... })
```

The bad news is, the text.js plugin is also included - it adds about 3K, and consists of (as far as I can tell) now entirely unnecessary code for loading external text files. I know 3K isn't much, but I'm trying to keep my code highly optimized, and as far as I understand the code for the text plugin is not at all necessary if my text dependencies are inlined. I can keep the text plugin out by adding `exclude=text` to my `r.js` call, but if I do, I get an error when I try to use the optimized code in the browser saying the text.js plugin couldn't be loaded.

So:

1. Is there any reason the text.js plugin is **actually required** here?
2. If not, is there a **configuration option** for `r.js` that can fix this behavior, or
3. Is there an **easy shim** for the text.js plugin that I can include to convince Require.js that the unnecessary plugin is loaded?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The text plugin is really required since RequireJS needs to check if the plugin implements the method `normalize` before retrieving the proper module ID.

The way to remove the text plugin from the build is to use the `onBuildWrite` setting to create an empty plugin module as described on this issue comment: https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/issues/116#issuecomment-4185237 - This feature should land on a future version of r.js

**Edit:**

r.js now have a setting called `stubModules` that does exactly that:

```
//Specify modules to stub out in the optimized file. The optimizer will
//use the source version of these modules for dependency tracing and for
//plugin use, but when writing the text into an optimized layer, these
//modules will get the following text instead:
//If the module is used as a plugin:
// define({load: function(id){throw new Error("Dynamic load not allowed: " + id);}});
//If just a plain module:
// define({});
//This is useful particularly for plugins that inline all their resources
//and use the default module resolution behavior (do *not* implement the
//normalize() method). In those cases, an AMD loader just needs to know
//that the module has a definition. These small stubs can be used instead of
//including the full source for a plugin.
stubModules : ['text']
```

For more r.js options check the [example.build.js](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js) file.

Comment: OK, thanks - I'll try this out. Essentially the answer is (3) make a shim, which I can work out in my build process.

Comment: For posterity - I made a shim like this: `define("text",{load:function(){}});` and appended it to the beginning of my optimized file. Seems to work fine

Comment: Was wondering the same thing. `stubModules: ['text']` does the trick in newer versions of RequireJS.

Comment: does not work for me: `Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory`