# Play 2.3.10 - sbt-rjs error for text.js: Cannot read property 'normalize' of undefined

Tags: playframework, requirejs, sbt-rjs

Environment: Play 2.3.10; sbt 0.13.5; sbt-rjs 1.0.1

I have tried the suggested solutions to similar questions on play-framework Google group and StackOverflow, but have not been able to solve this issue so far. I have posted the same question on [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/YXvCPxi4C0g).

I have upgraded Play from 2.2.3 to 2.3.10 and get the following error on running **activator dist**:

```
[info] TypeError: Cannot read property 'normalize' of undefined
```

Here is the line of code that throws the error:

```
define([
    ...,
    'text!ui.template.html',
    ...
]
```

**build.js** contains the following:

```
require.config({
    ...
    ...
    paths : {
        ...,
        text: 'empty:',
        ...
    }
    ...
});
```

**config.js**, with the actual paths, looks like this:

```
require.config({
    ...
    ...
    paths : {
        ...,
        text: '../bower_components/requirejs-plugins/lib/text',
        ...
    }
    ...
});
```

All the scripts that I want rjs to work on are inside *public/scripts*. Here are the relevant contents of **build.sbt**:

```
JsEngineKeys.engineType := JsEngineKeys.EngineType.Node

pipelineStages := Seq(rjs, digest, gzip)

includeFilter in rjs := new FileFilter {
  val scriptsDir = (baseDirectory.value / "public" / "scripts").getAbsolutePath
  def accept(file: File) = file.getAbsolutePath.startsWith(scriptsDir)
}

//excludeFilter in rjs := GlobFilter("text")

excludeFilter in rjs := new FileFilter {
  def accept(file: File) = file.getName.equals("text.js")
}

RjsKeys.mainModule := "app"

RjsKeys.mainConfigFile := new File("scripts/build.js")

RjsKeys.baseUrl := "scripts"
```

And here are the contents of **plugins.sbt**:

```
// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.10")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-gzip" % "1.0.0")
```

I added the *excludeFilter* in build.sbt based on suggestions [here](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/issues/221), and have also tried *excludeFilter in rjs := GlobFilter("text.js")* and *excludeFilter in rjs := GlobFilter("text")*.

I have also tried adding *stubModules : ['text']* to build.js, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196977/how-can-i-prevent-the-require-js-optimizer-from-including-the-text-plugin-in-opt).

If I remove *text: 'empty:'* from build.js, I get the following error:

```
[info] Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/path/to/target/web/rjs/build/scripts/text.js'
```

I would appreciate any pointers to what I am missing here.

Thanks.

Comment: I switched to sbt.rjs 1.0.7 and modified _SbtRjs.scala_ to print `optimizerMappings` inside method `private def runOptimizer`, and text.js is not included there. I am not really sure why it still gets included during optimization. Anyone has any ideas?